# How Do I Output Boolean Variables to Screen in ReactJS Typescript?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I want to show the value of a boolean variable on screen in my ReactJS app. Here is my code:

```
const MyComponent = (props) => {

  let x = false;
  
  return (<div>
    <div>
      <p>Hello {props.value} Bye {x} Done</p>
    </div></div>
  );
};

export default MyComponent;
```

The screen should show `Hello true Bye false Done`.

However, I don't see any boolean values, only `Hello Bye Done`. Why is this? How can I output the booleans to the screen? If I use a number instead of a boolean, it shows up fine.

Comment: Did you try Hello {String(props.value)} Bye {String(X)} Done

Comment: I used `toString` which works similarly.

Answer (score 1):

Try making those values as string

```
{`${value}`}
or 
{value.toString()}
```

Answer (score 0):

Even though you wrap the variable in {}, you still need to add `.toString()` to it to get it to render. Thus the correct line is:

```
<p>Hello {props.value.toString()} Bye {x.toString()} Done</p>
```